# On Hover Link move Div Horizontally to current hovered Link position

Tags: javascript, html

I have a menu with 5 links, Each individual link has the same class and ID "navbarLink"
And I also have another div (which is a skewed shape) "#hoveredLink" that moves from 0 to the actual hovered link position (in the background) I want this shape to take the full width of the hovered link (since they're different on width since each one has more or less text). So My intention is to move this "#hoveredLink" horizontally to reach the position of the "navbarLink" actually hovered.

Haven't succeed yet!

```
window.onload = function() {
    var bsDiv = document.getElementById("hoveredLink");
    var x;

    $("navbarLink").hover(function() {
        x = document.getElementById("hoveredLink").left;
        bsDiv.style.left = x + "px";
    });
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: HTML with repeated ID values is invalid. IDs must be unique. This often leads to unexpected behavior. Generally you should just use a class.

Comment: You really should include your HTML. Also, your jQuery selector for that element is faulty. It's missing the hash symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is this?
If it is not, put an example html.

```js
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
var up = document.getElementById("up");

  menu.onmouseover = function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName != "SPAN"){ return; } // If everything is DIV, you can choose another condition to separate the children from the father.
    
    up.style.left = e.target.offsetLeft - 10 + "px";
    up.style.width = e.target.offsetWidth + 20 + "px";
  
  };
  
  menu.onmouseleave= function(e){ // Being the event in the parent is not lost between son and son
  
    up.style.width = 0 + "px";
    up.style.left = 0 + "px";
    
  };
```

```css
.content{
  position: relative;
}
#up{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
transition: all 0.25s;
}
#menu > span{
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div id="up"></div>
  <div id="menu">
    <span>Link 1</span>
    <span>Link_Link 2</span>
    <span>Link3</span>
    <span>Link 4...</span>
    <span>L5</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only flaw is the initial position. You might want to move everything inside the `for` statement into a named function and call the it on the first menu item initially.

Comment: No problem.
I have only left the basic idea, many changes can be made both in the beginning, in the transition and in the loss of focus. But I don't know what he wants.

Comment: woww thanks a lot @Antonio Torres, this is exactly what I needed :D!! and it works!!

Comment: is there a way to restore positioning on hover out to the initial which is top:0 left:0? @AntonioTorres

Comment: what if I want to increase 10 pixels to each side of the width? I can do this??

 20 + e.target.offsetWidth + "px"? @AntonioTorres

Comment: @AntonioTorres I've found my way to make the element to get back to default position if the mouse leaves the link!

var menu = document.getElementById("navbarRight");
for(var i in menu.childNodes){
  menu.childNodes[i].onmouseover = function(e){
  document.getElementById("hoveredLink").style.left = e.target.offsetLeft + "px";
  document.getElementById("hoveredLink").style.width = e.target.offsetWidth + "px"; 
  }; 
  menu.childNodes[i].onmouseleave = function(){
  document.getElementById("hoveredLink").style.left = "-100vw"; 
  }; 
}

Comment: @AntonioTorres the thing is that there's a gap between each link (a margin-right: 30px) n each link, so if you scroll between links the hover element gets back to default position really fast and then gets back in to the next hovered link, there's a way to smooth this. transition?

Comment: I have modified the example, I think I have put everything you have said. I have used the bubbling to remove the for but you have to separate the children of the parent in the function, there are many ways to do it and I still do not know what your html is like so I have done it as it was best for me.